# The position error with mdDialog in AngularJS

Tags: css, angularjs, angular-material, mddialog

I am using `mdDialog` in `Angular Material` in my project, but using two different way:

**Way 1**:

```
  $mdDialog.show($mdDialog.confirm()
    .ok('Submit')
    .cancel('Cancel'));
```

This use the default `confirm` dialog, which will display the dialog in the browser middle,

It will generate md-dialog-container as:

```
<div class="md-dialog-container ng-scope" tabindex="-1" style="top: 2186px; height: 471px;">
```

**Way 2**:

```
  var template = '<md-dialog>'
    + '    <md-dialog-content>'
    + '    </md-dialog-content>'
    + '    <md-dialog-actions>'
    + '      </md-dialog-actions>'
    + '</md-dialog>';

  $mdDialog.show({
      template: template,
      parent: angular.element(document.body),
      disableParentScroll: false
  });
```

It will generate md-dialog-container as:

```
<div class="md-dialog-container ng-scope" tabindex="-1" style="top: 0px; height: 471px;">
```

However, this one with `top: 0px` in `md-dialog-container` which display on the top of page, not in the middle of browser.

What's the difference between these two, is there a way I can make the `Way 2` as the same css style as `Way 1`? Thanks!

**Demo:**

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/amEdYv?editors=1010#0

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PGEkKE (If changing the Angular Material to older version, such as 0.7.1, it will display correctly)

Comment: I get the same `top` for both dialogs - http://codepen.io/camden-kid/pen/ORzrPj?editors=1010#0

Comment: Hi @camden_kid, thanks for your response, This is mine  http://codepen.io/anon/pen/PGEkKE. If you change angular material version to `0.7.1`, it displays correctly.

Comment: @camden_kid, if you add more content and make the page scrollable you can see the error: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/amEdYv?editors=1010#0

Answer (score -1):

I have managed to reach the same result by adding a CSS entry for `md-dialog`:

```
md-dialog {
  height: auto;
  vertical-align: central;
  align-items: center;
}
```

Example in codepen: http://codepen.io/ther/pen/YGYwBA

Comment: Thanks for your response, but your solution is not correct, please see my demo, and also using the latest version of Angular Material(1.0.9 for example), cheers.